# Windows Shrinked Volume does not appear in Ubuntu Install Setup

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I have windows 10. I shrank my HDD to make 30GB room for Ubuntu installation, as picture shows:
[image]

But when I start machine with Ubuntu image and proceed to install location, surprisingly it shows the volume with 0 as size!:

[image]

and shows the original 256GB drive in full capacity. How should I install?

**UPDATE**

I brought up Gpartition on Ubuntu to delete the partition but it's not listed. I can do anything on other partitions.
[image]

And after this my laptop doesn't even bootup to windows! Giving  following error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
On the Live desktop open GParted.

Delete the partition you have created in Windows before - and create a new extended partition.
Create a new partition under the extended partition (size : matching RAM) - format it with swap.
Create a new partition under the extended partition (size : rest free space) - format it with ext4.

Close GParted and start the installer.
Choose Something else when asked.
Select the ext4 partition for Ubuntu.

Comment: I couldn't do it. The partition was not available to delete

Comment: I added edits :)

Comment: @Arash : Unfortunately there must have been something completely going wrong when you edited the partitions in Windows and you have to reinstall everything including Windows ... so, please never do this again ... there is a golden rule that says : never work on system partitions from within a running system ! :)

Comment: Can I recover my windows data after installing windows again?

Comment: @Arash : You can try to save the data using Ubuntu installation media - on Live desktop open the nautilus file manager and when you can access the Windows files, copy them over to an external drive. When this is not possible, you're lost ... sorry to be the harbinger of this ! :)